Python just dies out without opening firefox
so im trying to translate a website with selenium and firefox profiles, this is my code:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

#Firefox driver settings
options = Options()
options.add_argument('-headless')

options.set_preference('intl.accept_languages', 'en-US, en')
browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
browser.maximize_window()

browser.get('https://www.google.com')

and it just runs and then stops running, nothing happens
i tried meddling around with the options because i initially used to use firefox_profile and its been since deprecated.

The problem you encounter is that you use the -headless option which, by definition, runs firefox without opening any window. Just remove the option to get your browser popping up on screen.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

#Firefox driver settings
options = Options()

options.set_preference('intl.accept_languages', 'en-US, en')
browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
browser.maximize_window()

browser.get('https://www.google.com')


thank you so much, i dont know how i missed that, but then again, i saw it and i thought its running something else headless
